# Dynamically Modify Ruby Instance Variable in Array

Tags: ruby, variables, reference

I have an array `["moniker", @moniker]` where the moniker can be any one of around 100 instance variables and its string representation. I want to change what the instance variable located at index 1 is referencing (not that data itself, which may very well be immutable). Just doing `array[1] = newData` doesn't work because it just changes whats in the array. I know this would be simple in C, but I'm struggling to find a way to do this in Ruby.

Comment: This is quite an interesting question.  Thank you for asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struggle is because you are thinking like a C programmer, where you have access to the underlying pointers, and where everything is mutable.  In C, The array would store a pointer to a mutable integer, and you could change the integer whenever you want.  In Ruby, every variable is a reference to an object, *and* numbers are immutable objects.  So, @moniker is a reference to an object, the integer *4*.  When you create the array, you copy that reference into the array, so now the integer *4* has two references: One from @moniker, and one from the array.  As you have found, changing the reference in the array does not change the reference named @moniker--it still refers to the object *4*.

## "Box" a reference in an array

This is not really a Ruby way of doing things.  I'm showing it because it might help to illustrate how Ruby works with references.

You can box a reference in an array:

```
@moniker = [4]
a = ["moniker", @moniker]
```

This requires you to deference the array when you want access to the underlying object:

```
@moniker.first
a[1].first
```

But now you can change the underlying integer in @moniker and the array will see the change:

```
@moniker[0] = 42
p a[1].first    # => 42
```

## Encapsulate the number in a mutable object.

Being an object oriented language, you might encapsulate that number in a mutable object.

```
class Moniker
  attr_accessor :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

(`attr_accessor :value` builds reader and writer methods for the instance variable `@value`).

```
@moniker = Moniker.new(4)
a = ["monikier", @moniker]
@moniker.value = 42
p a[1].value    # => 42
```

You would obviously chose a better name than "value."  I couldn't because I don't know what the value represents.

## Why these two solutions work

*This was a comment by Jörg W Mittag, but it deserves to be part of the answer*:

It may seem obvious, but I wanted to mention it explicitly: the two solutions are the same solution. The first uses an already existing class with generic semantics, the the second defines a new class with precise semantics for the specific encapsulated value. But in both cases, it's about wrapping the immutable value in a mutable value and mutating the "outer" value.

Answer (score 1):

@moniker never got into the array but its value did.

In IRB:

```
@moniker = 4
a = ["moniker", @moniker]
 => ["moniker", 4]
```

You're just working with the value in the array anyway so just change it and you're good to go:

```
a[1] = 5
a
 => ["moniker", 5]
```

You might want to consider a hash:

```
h = {:moniker => @moniker}
 => {:moniker=>4} 

h[:moniker] = 5
h
 => {:moniker=>5}
```